# Regex that only allows a specific set of characters (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will only allow characters e, b, z, l to be typed in the user input.

I believe this is wrong ? :

```
/[ebzl]*/i
```

I know I need to use a class but I don't know how and couldn't find any relevant tutorials for the above online.

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
  if (/[ebzl]*/i.test($(this).val())) {
     // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: `^[ebzl]*$` (allows zero or more chars in the given list), yep it's a correct one. REplace `*` with `+` to allow one or more chars.

Answer (score 3):

Anchor your regex:

```
if (/^[ebzl]+$/i.test($(this).val())) {
```